# CodePen turn out to white blank page

Tags: javascript, html, api, codepen

Here is my Codepen Link :

[https://codepen.io/ShikhaA/pen/ALJXyk](http://CodePenio/ShikhaA/pen/ALJXyk)

It was working properly from past few months. But now it turned to white blank page. i tested it to other web browsers too still the same.

But when i tried the same code in local host i can see the output.

Thanks.

Comment: in the console I see *HTTPS security is compromised by http://ip-api.com*

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I was getting a blank output on CodePen because I hadn't added vuetify to my Vue instance. Make sure your Vue instantiation has this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(), //this line must be there
  ...
});
```

Also make sure you are referencing Vue and Vuetify JavaScript libraries as well as the Vuetify CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the color of the title is white, just as the background. It actually does generate an output, it's just not visible. Try to change the color of the `.title`-class.

Comment: Thank you after changing the background color all i can see is "Hello" but not the desire output. if you extract my codepen and run on your browser the output is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your console, you'll see that the request to ip-api.com is loaded over `HTTP` and Codepen want's you to load it over `HTTPS`. Therefore it blocks your request and that's why the screen stays empty.

The error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/ShikhaA/pen/ALJXyk' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ip-api.com/json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The only thing that shows is the title ("Hello"), but that's white, just like the background, so not visible until you select it.

Comment: That's actually not the error here. It's way simpler (see my answer). EDIT: You ninja'd me.

Comment: @StuntHacks Yeah i removed that part by accident when removing some other tips, saw it after I posted my answer!